Missing Furigana / Phonetic Guide button in Excel
Like the title says, I am trying to add furigana to japanese Kanji but there is no such button in the font group, and if I manually add a custom group with the phonetic guides, or phonetic settings, nothing happens if I click on them.
I read online that you have to have 'japanese language features' installed. I have added the japanese IME and checked every box in the japanese language settings.
So what else am I missing?
My windows is Windows 11 Enterprise Version 23H2
I'm using Excel from 'Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise'

Where did you read this exactly?

@Ramhound here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-phonetic-guides-to-east-asian-text-c03ad8e4-799b-499e-89a2-c749fc5397e8

Please check the version number of your Office via clicking File > Account, under Product Information, you may find it.
Then go to Excel File > Options > Language, make sure that Japanese is at the top on both, display and proofing language.
(If Japanese does not appear, you need to add it.)

@Emily Setting Japanese as preferred proofing language worked!
